# tikz: axis values overflow

Tags: tikz-pgf, axis, number

I need to enter values in the vertical axis: this is my attempt

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{modiagram}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\tikzset{axis line style/.style={thin, gray, -stealth}}
\newcommand*{\TickSize}{2pt}%

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

 \begin{figure}[p]
 \centering
 \MOsetup{
 names,
 names-style = {
 text height = 2.5ex,
 text depth = .5ex,
 draw = blue!80,
 yshift=-1cm,
 rounded corners
 }
 }
 \begin{MOdiagram}[style=fancy,labels,names,names-style-add={draw=blue,fill=blue!20},AO-width=10pt,lines={gray,thin}]
 \atom[\ch{I}]{left}{
 2s={0.5;pair},
 label = { 2sleft = {5s} },
 2p = {5;pair,pair,up},
 label = { 2pxleft = {$5\text{p}_x$} },
 label = { 2pyleft = {$5\text{p}_y$} },
 label = { 2pzleft = {$5\text{p}_z$} }
 }
 \atom[\ch{Cl}]{right}{
 2s={-0.5;pair}, 
 2p = {4;pair,pair,up},
 label = { 2sright = {3s} },
 label = { 2pxright = {$3\text{p}_x$} },
 label = { 2pyright= {$3\text{p}_y$} },
 label = { 2pzright = {$3\text{p}_z$} }
 }
 \molecule[\ch{ICl}]{
 2sMO, 2pMO = {;pair,pair,pair,pair,pair},
 label = { 2sigma = {$\sigma_s$} },
 label = { 2sigma* = {$\sigma_s^*$} },
 label = { 2psigma = {$\sigma_{z}$}},
 label = { 2psigma* = {$\sigma_{z}^*$}},
 label = { 2piy = {$\pi_{x}$}},
 label = { 2piz = {$\pi_{y}$}},
 label = { 2piy* = {$\pi_{x}^*$}},
 label = { 2piz* = {$\pi_{y}^*$}},
 }
 \draw[axis line style] (-1.25,-2.5) -- (-1.25,7.5);
\foreach \y/\ytext in {0,...,10}
    \draw[shift={(-1.25,\y)}] (2pt,0pt) -- (-2pt,0pt) node[left] {$\ytext$};
 \end{MOdiagram}
 \caption{MO diagram of \ch{ICl}. Created by Marco Atzori with \LaTeX}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, the values array overflows from the axis. How do I have to make it fit into the axis?

Thank you in advance

Comment: I have this error: `LaTeX3 Error: Variant form 'cNc' deprecated for base form`

Comment: Is a MOdiagram bug. I handmade solved this: https://bitbucket.org/cgnieder/modiagram/pull-requests/3/fix-bad-variants/diff

Comment: So, what do I have to do to compile your code?

Comment: search "modiagram.sty" on your computer, and delete/replace lines as show in the link

Comment: Simply modify these line `\foreach \y/\ytext in {0,...,7}
    \draw[shift={(-1.25,\y)}] (2pt,0pt) -- (-2pt,0pt) node[left] {$\ytext$};`

Comment: Instead of modifying the protected `modiagram.sty` file, I downloaded its new version and placed it in my local `texmf`. Then, I updated the `file name database`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I modified the loop to 7 instead of 10. And I put the zero at the bottom of the blue nodes text, not really knowing if this is the right place for you or not.

```
\foreach \y/\ytext in {0,...,10}
    \draw[shift={(-1.25,\y-3)}] (2pt,0pt) -- (-2pt,0pt) node[left] {$\ytext$};
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{modiagram}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\tikzset{axis line style/.style={thin, gray, -stealth}}
\newcommand*{\TickSize}{2pt}%

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

 \begin{figure}[p]
 \centering
 \MOsetup{
 names,
 names-style = {
 text height = 2.5ex,
 text depth = .5ex,
 draw = blue!80,
 yshift=-1cm,
 rounded corners
 }
 }
 \begin{MOdiagram}[style=fancy,labels,names,names-style-add={draw=blue,fill=blue!20},AO-width=10pt,lines={gray,thin}]
 \atom[\ch{I}]{left}{
 2s={0.5;pair},
 label = { 2sleft = {5s} },
 2p = {5;pair,pair,up},
 label = { 2pxleft = {$5\text{p}_x$} },
 label = { 2pyleft = {$5\text{p}_y$} },
 label = { 2pzleft = {$5\text{p}_z$} }
 }
 \atom[\ch{Cl}]{right}{
 2s={-0.5;pair}, 
 2p = {4;pair,pair,up},
 label = { 2sright = {3s} },
 label = { 2pxright = {$3\text{p}_x$} },
 label = { 2pyright= {$3\text{p}_y$} },
 label = { 2pzright = {$3\text{p}_z$} }
 }
 \molecule[\ch{ICl}]{
 2sMO, 2pMO = {;pair,pair,pair,pair,pair},
 label = { 2sigma = {$\sigma_s$} },
 label = { 2sigma* = {$\sigma_s^*$} },
 label = { 2psigma = {$\sigma_{z}$}},
 label = { 2psigma* = {$\sigma_{z}^*$}},
 label = { 2piy = {$\pi_{x}$}},
 label = { 2piz = {$\pi_{y}$}},
 label = { 2piy* = {$\pi_{x}^*$}},
 label = { 2piz* = {$\pi_{y}^*$}},
 }
 \draw[axis line style] (-1.25,-2.5) -- (-1.25,7.5);
\foreach \y/\ytext in {0,...,10}
\draw[shift={(-1.25,\y-3)}] (2pt,0pt) -- (-2pt,0pt) node[left] {$\ytext$};
 \end{MOdiagram}
 \caption{MO diagram of \ch{ICl}. Created by Marco Atzori with \LaTeX}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The best would be placing 0 at the bottom and 10 at the top

Comment: At which level do you want to set the zero? To the one of the text at the bottom or to the one of the lowest node `$\sigma_s$` or elsewhere?